# I am getting Tango Error Exception after upgrading to latest libraries

Tags: android, google-project-tango

I added

compile 'com.google.tango:sdk-base:1.53'

compile 'com.google.tango:support-base:1.53'
and removed the jar files

Here is the code snippet:
 Activity

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // Set render mode to RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY to force getting onDraw callbacks until
    // the Tango service is properly set up and we start getting onFrameAvailable callbacks.
    mSurfaceView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);
    // Check and request camera permission at run time.
    if (checkAndRequestPermissions()) {
        bindTangoService();
    }
}
/**
 * Initialize Tango Service as a normal Android Service.
 */
private void bindTangoService() {
    mTango = new Tango(PlaneActivity.this, new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Synchronize against disconnecting while the service is being used in the
            // OpenGL thread or in the UI thread.
            synchronized (PlaneActivity.this) {
                try {
                    TangoSupport.initialize();
                    mConfig = setupTangoConfig(mTango);
                    mTango.connect(mConfig);
                    startupTango();
                    mIsConnected = true;
                    setDisplayRotation();
                } catch (TangoOutOfDateException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.exception_out_of_date), e);
                    showsToastAndFinishOnUiThread(R.string.exception_out_of_date);
                } catch (TangoErrorException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.exception_tango_error), e);
                    showsToastAndFinishOnUiThread(R.string.exception_tango_error);
                } catch (TangoInvalidException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.exception_tango_invalid), e);
                    showsToastAndFinishOnUiThread(R.string.exception_tango_invalid);
                }

            }
        }
    });
}

     private TangoConfig setupTangoConfig(Tango tango) {
    // Create a new Tango Configuration and enable the Camera API
    TangoConfig config = tango.getConfig(TangoConfig.CONFIG_TYPE_DEFAULT);
    config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_DRIFT_CORRECTION, true);
    config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_COLORCAMERA, true);
    if (TangoApplication.getInstance().isSaveAdf())
        config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_LEARNINGMODE, true);
    return config;
}

 /**
 * Set up the callback listeners for the Tango Service and obtain other parameters required
 * after Tango connection.
 * Listen to updates from the RGB camera.
 */
private void startupTango() {
    // No need to add any coordinate frame pairs since we aren't using pose data from callbacks.

    ArrayList<TangoCoordinateFramePair> framePairs = new ArrayList<TangoCoordinateFramePair>();


    mTango.connectListener(framePairs, new Tango.TangoUpdateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPoseAvailable(TangoPoseData pose) {
            super.onPoseAvailable(pose);
        }

        @Override
        public void onXyzIjAvailable(TangoXyzIjData xyzIj) {
            super.onXyzIjAvailable(xyzIj);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFrameAvailable(int cameraId) {
            super.onFrameAvailable(cameraId);
            if (cameraId == TangoCameraIntrinsics.TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR) {
                if (mSurfaceView.getRenderMode() != GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY) {
                    mSurfaceView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
                }
                mIsFrameAvailableTangoThread.set(true);
                mSurfaceView.requestRender();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTangoEvent(TangoEvent event) {
            super.onTangoEvent(event);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPointCloudAvailable(TangoPointCloudData pointCloud) {
            super.onPointCloudAvailable(pointCloud);
        }
    });
}
```

Took learning mode permission onCreate

```
   startActivityForResult(
       Tango.getRequestPermissionIntent(Tango.PERMISSIONTYPE_ADF_LOAD_SAVE),
            Tango.TANGO_INTENT_ACTIVITYCODE);
```

The application crashes on  mTango.connect(mConfig); 
Here are the error logs

E/tango_client_api: TangoErrorType TangoService_connect(void*, TangoConfig): Enable color camera

05-07 12:46:02.649 25610-25841/com.projecttango.experiments.planefittingsample E/tango_client_api: TangoErrorType TangoService_connect(void*, TangoConfig): Internal Error: Connect failed internally: -1

05-07 12:46:02.653 25610-25841/com.projecttango.experiments.planefittingsample E/PlaneFittingActivity: Tango exception!
                                                                                                       com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoErrorException

Similar error I am getting when
I took the latest pull of tango samples https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-java

When running the java_model_correspondence_example the app crashes

05-07 12:53:32.819 189-767/? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 767 (Binder_2)

```
                                 [ 05-07 12:53:32.870 32331:32331 I/         ]
                                 Loading GLESv2 implementation libGLESv2_tegra_impl
```

05-07 12:53:33.139 32331-32371/com.projecttango.examples.java.modelcorrespondence E/tango_client_api: virtual void TangoMortician::binderDied(const android::wp&): Internal Error: TangoService died.

05-07 12:53:33.139 32331-32355/com.projecttango.examples.java.modelcorrespondence E/tango_client_api: TangoErrorType TangoService_connect(void*, TangoConfig): Internal Error: Connect failed internally: -1

05-07 12:53:33.139 32331-32354/com.projecttango.examples.java.modelcorrespondence E/tango: TangoClient.cc:494 Tango Service binder transaction failed! Transaction type code = 1, status = -32.

05-07 12:53:33.139 32331-32371/com.projecttango.examples.java.modelcorrespondence A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 32371 (Binder_3)

05-07 12:53:33.142 32331-32355/com.projecttango.examples.java.modelcorrespondence E/ModelCorrespondenceActivity: Tango exception!